# Using SSRS with Azure SQL databases

Tags: sql-server, azure, reporting-services

I have a requirement to set up SSRS for reporting with one of our web applications. Just now I have SSRS installed locally and pointing to the local version of the database for development purposes which is fine and works.

The live and test SQL databases are on Azure and I would like to be able to connect to them from the Report Designer locally to create the reports.

How can this be done? For example, should I create a SQL database on Azure and use the SSRS configuration manager to set this as the reporting database, then from within the report designed connect to the live or test database when creating the reports?

Comment: Presumably you are using an Azure Managed Sequence, so you would create your connection managers the same as you would for a on-premises server; just you would use the appropriate network path for your Azure Instance. I'm not really sure where you are stuck here.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I probably just didn't explain what I need very well, what I'm stuck on is this - when I open the config manager I need to connect to a SSRS instance, ie where I installed it during set-up.  Would I run the set-up against each Db I wanted to report on? Currently when I try to run the set-up again (trying to set up against a network server locally) I only have the option to repair, uninstall or upgrade.

Comment: *Normally* you would install the SSRS instance on the server running SQL Server; if you aren't then just remember you would need separate licence keys for SSRS to your SQL Server's. And it's an instance installation; you don't install SSRS to a database.

Comment: Thanks again. I've installed locally and it seems I can set up and change the reporting database in the config manager, which is pretty much what I need. If you want to put you comment in an answer I'll accept it

Comment: But locally <> In Azure. Installing the service locally isn't the right call here; unless this is for your local instance, not the one in Azure? But then what does the one in Azure have to do with anything in this question? Are you simply asking how to install an SSRS instance locally for development? If so, why mention your (production) SQL Server at all here?